# Procedure need for SQL Query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am a bit stuck on this to be honest, and I cant find a nice solution. No solution at all.

I have this table actor(id,Actor_Name) where the name is formatted as Actor-01 .. etc:

```
id        Actor_Name    
--------------------
01        Actor-01 
02        Actor-02 
03        Actor-03
```

What I need is, to increase the name of every one of these actors by one, using a procedure . Like this:

```
id        Actor_Name    
--------------------
01        Actor-02 
02        Actor-02 
03        Actor-04
```

Probably I need some kind of iteration , and I have tried a bit with cursors, but its mostly a disaster. If Anyone could provide some neat solution , or something I would be really happy!

Comment: I have tried a procedure with cursor , tried to use lpad() function too, but still its seems, broken. I think this might need a different approach.

Comment: Does the Actor part vary, or it is a fixed value?

Comment: its is fixed as far as I know.

Comment: "*icrease the name of every one of these actors by one*": shouldn't the result be then `Actor-02`, `Actor-03` and `Actor-04`?

Comment: Then it is a simpler problem, you don't need to use instr to find the position of the minus.   use SUBSTR to extract the number, and concatenation to build the replacement value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a cursor. I'm not 100% sure about desired format, but something like
`select CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Actor-01','[[:digit:]]+')as int) from dual;` returns 1 that can be incremented and stored (for instance `UPDATE table1 set col1 = 'Actor-0' || CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1,'[[:digit:]]+')as int)+1 WHERE ....`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like (not tested)

```
update actor set actor_name = 'Actor-' || lpad( to_char( id + 1), 2, '0' );
commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some concepts that may point toward a workable solution.

You can use INSTR to find the position of the minus sign.

```
SELECT INSTR('ACTOR-74','-') FROM DUAL
```

You can use SUBSTR to pull off the DIGITS

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ACTOR-74', 6) FROM DUAL
```

You can use TO_NUMBER to turn the digits into a number

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('1234') FROM DUAL
```

You can use concatenation to build a replacement value

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ACTOR-74',1,6) || 
       TO_CHAR(74 + 1, '09') FROM DUAL
```

Which yields a value that can be used in the update.

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET ACTOR_NAME = the-replacement-value
```

Comment: EvilTeach, thanks, my approach is something like this so far. Thanks for the input

Comment: all the solutions are assuming 2 digits.   is that a safe assumption?

Answer (score 1):

No need for a procedure.

```
merge into actor
using (
  select id, 
         substr(actor_name, 1, instr(actor_name, '-')) as name,
         to_number(substr(actor_name, instr(actor_name, '-') + 1)) as nr
  from actor
) t on (t.id = actor.id)
when matched then update
   set actor_name = t.name || to_char(nr + 1, 'FM09');
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93c02/1

Comment: I guess the old simple `update` will work as well in this case, won't it ? I mean no need for `merge`...

Comment: @a1ex07: yes it would. I prefer a merge in this case at it makes things clearer. The inner select documents the intention better (I think)

Comment: surely merge works as well. I guess it's just a matter of personal preferences...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
update (select id
             , replace( Actor_name
                      , substr(actor_name, -2)
                      , To_char(to_number(substr(actor_name, -2)) + 1, 'fm00')
                      ) as New_Actor_name
             , Actor_name
         from actor
        ) a
set a.actor_name = a.new_actor_name;
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d225/3)

Comment: what does this fm00 stands for ?

Comment: @MarkS. It's a format model; '00' - two digits(allowing leading zeros) and `FM`(format model modifier) forces `to_char` function to return value without leading or trailing blanks

Answer (score 0):

Using a stored procedure for such a simple task seems like overkill.

```
update ACTOR
set substr(ACTOR_NAME,1,length(ACTOR_NAME)-2)||to_number(substr(ACTOR_NAME,-2,2))+1
where substr(ACTOR_NAME,-2,2) between '00' and '99'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have been close using a cursor, but probably didn't know that cursors are READ-ONLY by default. To toggle this behavior, use the `for update` option in your cursor defintion:

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/for_update.php
(an additional explanation of the `for update` clause)

Then when looping through the cursor, you need to also use a clause which allows you to update the record last fetched by the cursor: `where current of`

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/current_of.php
("where current of" examples)

This should work with both anonymous pl/sql blocks or by a stored procedure definition.